# Merge Word Documents in Document Library

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, document-library, word-automation

There is need where I need to merge Word documents saved in a Document Library. I was looking for out of the box solution but did not come across one.

Please provide custom C# solution if there exists one.

Has any one succeed in implemention.

Comment: Dear Mancy,
Have you developed above solution. 
kindly provide complete solution.

Comment: I am sorry to say that this is a client solution so i have to keep it confidential. I have provided the core functions to you and they are working.

Comment: its working. 
Thank you.

Comment: Any proper solution to merge two documents located on SPO document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on this kind of a solution currently.  You will need to create a custom feature in order to achieve this. You can use the `OpenXML` DLL for this purpose. This DLL will allow you to merge the documents.

The following steps shall help you to develop:

1. download the word files locally
2. create a new word file that will hold the merged files.
3. upload the merged file to the document library

Use the following code for merging the files:

```
 //creates word file -- accepts complete file path with name as param
 void createWordFile(string fileName) 
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {                
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
            mainPart.Document = new Document(new Body());                
        }
    }

    //merges files with page break
    //params : source and destination file paths and unique value for AltChunkId
    public void MergeDocumentWithPagebreak(string sourceFile, string destinationFile, string AltChunkID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceFile, true))
            {
                string altChunkId = AltChunkID;
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                //Append page break
                Paragraph para = new Paragraph(new Run((new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
                mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(para, mainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);
                //Append file
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(destinationFile, FileMode.Open))
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }

    //uploads word file to the folder in the document set
    public void UploadFile(string newFileName, string folderURL)
    {
        SPFolder ds = SPContext.Current.Web.GetFolder(folderURL);

        using (FileStream strm = new FileInfo(newFileName).Open(FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[strm.Length];
            strm.Read(data, 0, (int)strm.Length);

            String fileToBeUploaded = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(newFileName);
            ds.Files.Add(fileToBeUploaded, data, true);
            ds.Update();
        }
    }
```

These functions will help you solve the issue.